# How do I find all the vertices of a particular property?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

How do I query Janus Graph to get all the vertices with a certain label?

This is the way I'm currently doing it. Where `MAX` is simply some arbitrary constant of the maximum theoretical size of the graph.

`graph.V().hasLabel("my-label").next(MAX)`

The other alternative is `next()` with no parameters but then I would have to iterate through using `hasNext()` until `hasNext()` is false. Is there any way to find all the vertices (return a list or array of type `Vertex`) matching a certain label without having to artificially set the search ceiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `toList()`:

```
g.V().hasLabel("my-label").toList()
```